# Pass iterating object to javascript function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In Ajax call populating data dynamically.

**Requirement :** After populating if we click on button it should invoke JavaScript function along with required to pass object.
In JavaScript we need to access data using like value.id, value.title, value.description..... (Expected result)
But i am unable to fetch data from function argument, i tried with **stringify, parse** methods but didn't.

Please tell me, how can i access in JavaScript function?

```
success : function(data) {
 var listData = null;
 $.each(data.documentsList,function(index, value) { 
   //some logic ----------(iam able to get value.id, value.title, value.description...)
   listData += '<button value="Update" onclick="updateDocument(\''+ value + '\')">Update</button>'
   //some logic ----------
  });//each loop end
 $('#list').html(listData);
 },//success end

function updateDocument(document) {
    console.log("updateDocument" + document);  //[object object]
    console.log(document.title); //undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `value` is being stringified to `[object object]`. You can check that by observing your html in DevTools.

That's why, the function never receives the original object, hence attributes (id, value etc.) are `undefined`.

I suggest keeping the original data received from AJAX in a variable, and concatenating item's id in HTML. So, in `updateDocument()`, you will first need to search the received id in the list, and then act on that.

Another way would be to use `JSON.stringify(value)` and concatenate the result with the HTML. Upon receiving the value in `updateDocument()`, parse the JSON received, and act against it. But this will make your HTML clumsy and lengthy.